# Definition of finite-dimensional 'self-dual algebra' over a field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory, duality-theorems, algebras

In some informal notes that are not publicly available and for which I do not have permission to reproduce here, there is a reference to a 'finite-dimensional self-dual algebra over a field $K$'.

I can't find much about this, so I need to clarify what is most likely meant by it. It is discussed in the context of homological algebra and I assume (from the context) that it is meant to be a self-injective ring.

My best guess is that it relates to the connection between algebras and coalgebras rather than anything to do with duals of vector spaces. I haven't checked all the details yet but there appears to be a functor from the category of unital $K$-coalgebras to the category of unital $K$-algebras (not necessarily commutative) and 'self-duality' means that this functor is an isomorphism, so that there is a one-to-one correspondence between algebras and coalgebras. Does this sound right?

Comment: Would the definition given in the abstract of the following paper be what you needed? https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0622

Comment: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~mgersten/self-dual.pdf no?